# Handling 'content' - attribute in TSX?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, schema.org, tsx

I am working on an application that makes use of schema.org. I have the following line:

`<span itemProp="priceCurrency" content="EUR">€</span>`

Based on [the schema.org docs](https://schema.org/Offer) the `content` attribute is allowed.

> Note that both RDFa and Microdata syntax allow the use of a "content=" attribute for publishing simple machine-readable values alongside more human-friendly formatting.

However, I don't know how to fix this TS error:
`Property 'content' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLSpanElement>, HTMLSpanElement>'`

Grateful for any ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the TS-error:

```
declare module 'react' {
    interface HTMLAttributes<T> {
        // extends React's HTMLAttributes
        content?: string;
    }
}
```